# Access Denied when workflow accesses _api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a workflow that worked until this past Friday 2014/10/24.  Now whenever the workflow attempts to access `_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/Items` I get an Access Denied error.  I had another user start the workflow and it results in the same thing.  I went to the URL that was giving the error in the workflow and I was able to load it just fine.

I am using SharePoint online.  Is there maybe an update that they did that I need to work around or fix?  Some of my users have access to the permissions, could they have messed something up?  I am admin and have full access to the site, and couldn't find anything different with permissions.

Comment: Try republishing the workflow and see if it solves it

Comment: @Choggo I've tried that.  It also started happening on two workflows.

Comment: The "Worked until 24/10" is the part troubling me. Have there been any recent updates to the environment? Have you tred giving the [Workflow App more priviledges?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159(v=office.15).aspx) You can try setting the [Http Call header](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118876/call-http-web-service-unauthorized/118889#118889) and see what happens

Comment: @Choggo I tried giving the app more permissions, that didn't change anything.  I also don't see an http call header in the properties of the email.

Comment: This is happening when you try to send an e-mail? Do you have the full URL that the workflow calls? If you call it in the browser does it work?

Comment: @Choggo specifically it's when i try to get the user's email.  I just separated out that call and verified that's the problem.  As I specified in the OP, I went to the URL that is giving the error and it loads without issue.